# Logistic Regression: Interpretation regarding Block 0 and Block 1 on SPSS output

Tags: regression, logistic, spss, predictive-models

We received the following two tables as a result of a logistic regression analysis with by Enter and backward LR methods. The two outputs, Block 0 and 1, are provided below.

Despite attempts to explain it in various ways, we are puzzled **as to why only such a small difference is observed between the null model and the model with multiple variables (predictors)**, which we assumed was the fitting model in consideration to the research question at hand. It is also worth mentioning that our attempts to reduce the number of variables resulted in a less significant model, so that was not an option. Additionially, we would also like to ask if it is possible to compare the classification tables for different "N"? [image]

[image]

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by the two models not showing much difference?

Comment: I meant for the two classifications, between Block 0 (with no predictors) and Block 1 (with predictors). In other words, we wanted to know how we can increase the classification accuracy between the two blocks.

Comment: Logistic regression just predicts the probability of being a 1. If you want to use it for classification you need to define a cut-off. At the moment SPSS is using its default for this. I do not use SPSS myself so I have no idea whether it is possible to change it and if so how.

Comment: The default classification cut-off we've used is 0.5, but do you believe that there is a potential problem with the classification at first glance?

Comment: You can set the cutoff.  You might want to use the sample proportions for this or, if there are different error costs, take that into account in setting the threshold.